# Update query if statement for Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, case, conditional-statements

I need to update newly created column in my oracle table. To do so I need to use existing values in row to decide how to populate this column, I am getting error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException -> See Debug Output for details
```

This is my query:

```
UPDATE
    SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME
SET
    OCO= IF CO= 'Y' AND COM='Y' THEN 
{
    'Y'
} ELSE
{
    'N'
}
END IF;
```

Any suggestions on syntax?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could use **CASE** expression in the `SET` clause.

For example,

```
UPDATE table
SET schema.column =  CASE
                        WHEN CO= 'Y' AND COM='Y' THEN
                          'Y'
                        ELSE
                          'N'
                     END
```

Comment: if the value of 'CO' or 'COM' was being updated in the same statement, will the case block consider old value of the 'CO' and 'COM' columns or the updated values?

Comment: @gkapagunta Oracle follows the ACID property for transaction. Read more about it and you will find your answer in your question itself. By the way answer is NO.