# how to update multiple rows in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to update multiple rows with different values for all different records, but don't have any idea how to do that, i am using below sql to update for single record but i have 200 plus records to update

```
update employee
set staff_no = 'ab123'
where depno = 1
```

i have 50 dep and within those dep i need to update 200 plus staff no. any idea.
At the moment if i just do a

```
 select * from Departments
```

i can see list of all employee which needs staff no updating.

```
UPDATE person
   SET staff_no = 
       CASE person_no
            WHEN 112 THEN 'ab123'
            WHEN 223 THEN 'ab324'
            WHEN 2343 THEN 'asb324'
            and so on.....


       END
```

Comment: for example if depno =1 set staffno = ab123   ...... if depno = 2 set staffno =ab321

Comment: Are you saying you need to update 200 records all having different values? Is there a way to compute those values?

Comment: i have around 150 person_id's all look different, i need to update staff_no against those person id's, so in short 150 person_no's and 150 staff_no's

Comment: Create a sqlfiddle with some sample DDL and date showing relation if the answers below don't satisfy.

Comment: @srk786 don't panic. even if there is no test db where you can get comfortable with the technique, nothing willbe altered in your prod db until you `COMMIT` - try it for 2 small departments first, check the results, issue a `ROLLBACK`.

Answer (score 10):

You should be able to use [`MERGE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606) statement to do it in a single shot. However, the statement is going to be rather large:

```
MERGE INTO employee e
USING (
   SELECT 1 as d_id, 'cd234' as staff_no FROM Dual
       UNION ALL
   SELECT 2 as d_id, 'ef345' as staff_no FROM Dual
       UNION ALL
   SELECT 3 as d_id, 'fg456' as staff_no FROM Dual
       UNION ALL
   ... -- More selects go here
   SELECT 200 as d_id, 'za978' as staff_no FROM Dual
) s
ON (e.depno = S.d_id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET e.staff_no= s.staff_no
```

Comment: Why MERGE for only an update? The update statement is meant for that.

Answer (score 4):

use a case expression

```
UPDATE employee
   SET staff_no = 
           CASE depno
                WHEN 1 THEN 'ab123'
                WHEN 2 THEN 'ab321'
                --...
                ELSE staff_no
           END
 WHERE depno IN ( 1, 2 ) -- list all cases here. use a subquery if you don't want to / cannot enumerate
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, will it work if i put all the dep no as case and within that case put all staff number, there is no sub query, i just pulled up the department table and than i will put all staff numbers manually

Comment: You can cater for all possible `depno` values in a single case expression. I'd recommend to use the `ELSE` branch to keep the old value to safeguard against unexpected `depno` s.

Comment: will it be possible if you can please write the sql query/ case statement where i have 150 different person id's and i want to update 150 staff_no against those id's, i will be putting in person_id's and staff number  manually as an update within a query

Comment: sorry sir, i gladly help people but i won't do your work for you ;-). Even more so as i'm not so sure about your data model.

Comment: please have a look at my question. 2nd part i am going to execute that. does it look ok

Answer (score 3):

For conditional update, you could use multiple update statements, or use **CASE** expression in the **SET clause**.

Something like,

```
UPDATE table
SET schema.column =  CASE
                        WHEN column1= 'value1' AND column2='value2' THEN
                          'Y'
                        ELSE
                          'N'
                     END
```

I wish you tried to search for a similar question on this site, there was a recent question and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28581198/update-query-if-statement-for-oracle/28581240#28581240) was my answer.

Comment: its really stressing, i need to update on production database, i never used the case statement before, i am going to edit my question with what i am going to use and please if you can help whether i am doing the right way

Answer (score 1):

If you have two tables like:

```
CREATE TABLE test_tab_1 (id NUMBER, name VARCHAR2(25));

CREATE TABLE test_tab_2 (id NUMBER, name VARCHAR2(25));
```

You can use `UPDATE` statement as below:

```
UPDATE test_tab_1
SET test_tab_1.name = (SELECT test_tab_2.name FROM test_tab_2
WHERE test_tab_1.id = test_tab_2.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly your db set up is, but for me I solved a similar issue using some simple PLSQL.

Let's say you have two tables:

1. "request" table with many columns one being a "date" column and its primary key being "id"
2. "item" table with many columns with one also being a "date" column and another being a pointer to the request it belongs to called "request_id"

And let's say this is for when a user is making a purchase request for one or more items, a one to many relationship, and so the date columns on the items should match that of the request they belong to.

Now let's say the date column on the request has been left blank accidentally but thankfully not the dates of the items. And so we want to updated the request date column to match that of their corresponding items' date value. And so for each request, take one of its items and take the item.date and set the request.date to this item.date using PLSQL:

```
begin
for iteration_row in
(select distinct r.id as r_id_from_select, i.date as i_date_from_select
  from request r
    join item i on item.request_id = r.id)
loop
  update request r_to_update
  set date = iteration_row.i_date_from_select
  where r_to_update.id = iteration_row.r_id_from_select
end loop;
end;
```

Another example of PLSQL looping through the select but this one is not updating like I am above:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49635601/2888009